# Apache2: two redirects

Tags: redirect, apache2

I would like to redirect all URLs to https on my host and root folder to sub-folder.

My configuration:

```
Redirect permanent / https://myhost.com/ 
RedirectMatch ^/$ /sub-folder/
```

The first redirect works well, all http requests are redirected to https, but the second one does nothing.

Any advice, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you put this configuration?

Comment: To /etc/apache/sites-available/myhost.conf (symlink to sites-enabled ofc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I handled it. Problem was that first redirect was redirected to port 443 so the second redirect has to be managed in VirtualHost:443. And as you said, the quotes are required in RedirectMatch directive.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem is with your first rule:

```
Redirect permanent / https://myhost.com/
```

Which could be changed to:

```
Redirect permanent http://myhost.com/ https://myhost.com/
```

Additionally, the regular expression doesn't seem to work unless it's inside quotes, so `^/$` should be changed to `"^/$"`

The second redirect is not observed because the first redirect occurs an infinite number of times.

I was able to debug this by adding a couple of entries to my `/etc/hosts` file as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 kerneldeimos.local
127.0.0.1 subdomain.kerneldeimos.local
```

I then added your rewrite rules (using a subdomain instead of HTTPS for convenience):

```
Redirect permanent / http://subdomain.kerneldeimos.local
RedirectMatch "^/$" /sub-folder/
```

It worked after I changed my config to the following:

```
Redirect permanent http://kerneldeimos.local http://subdomain.kerneldeimos.local
RedirectMatch "^/$" /sub-folder/
```